# Do Heavy objects like planets and stars create Curve in spactime fabric?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, curvature

According to Newton moon revolves around the earth because of gravitational pull! But Einsteins quoted that its not the pull but Earth's mass creates a curve in spacetime and Moon revolves on the edge of that curve, thats his definition of gravity. If it's true then how much bigger curve sun created due to its mass and is our all solar system within that curve?

Comment: Suggestion to the question (v2): Replace the word _curve_ with the word _curvature._

Answer (score 1):

When you ask "how curved is spacetime?" there isn't a simple answer because curvature is a complicated property and can't be described with a simple number.

However a good way to get a feel for the curvature of spacetime is to measure the acceleration of a freely moving body. By this I mean if you were stationary with respect to the Sun, and you dropped an object, how fast that object would accelerate towards the Sun. If spacetime was flat, i.e. not curved, the dropped object wouldn't accelerate at all - it would just float next to you. If spacetime is curved the object will accelerate away from you, and the bigger the curvature the faster the object accelerates.

To a very good approximation the acceleration is just given by [Newton's law of universal gravitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation), which tells us that the acceleration towards a massive body is:

$$ a = \frac{GM}{r^2} \tag{1} $$

where $M$ is the mass of the body, $r$ is the distance to the body and $G$ is a constant called [the gravitational constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_constant).

So if you're comparing the curvature caused by the Sun with the curvature caused by the Earth then you just have to compare the masses. The mass of the Sun is $1.9891 \times 10^{30}$ kg and the mass of the Earth is $5.972 \times 10^{24}$ kg so the Sun is about 330,000 times heavier than the Earth. At the same distance $r$ from the two bodies the Sun will produce an acceleration 330,000 times larger than the Earth will.

The part of the Solar System farthest from the Sun is the [Oort cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oort_cloud), which extends out to around a light year. We can calculate the value of the acceleration due to the Sun at that distance and we get:

$$ a \approx 1.5 \times 10^{-12} \,\text{ms}^{-2} $$

This is very very small, but it isn't zero. So even at the farthest extremes of the Solar System the curvature caused by the Sun can still be felt.

Answer (score 0):

All matter creates a curvature in space-time. (gravity) It is simply that as the mass of an object decreases (M in the above equation) the effect of that curvature becomes extremely small, or as the distance increases (r in the above example) it decreases sharply.  The effect is *always* there when mass is present, in some degree.